# Clicking an image using webcam in Tkinter Python and Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to develop a code through which I could access the webcam and display the video in a Tkinter Window. I have been able to access the webcam,load the video, and even stop the video using the reference code [Tkinter nested mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252056/tkinter-nested-mainloop)

What I want in addition is having a "CLICK" button which would capture the video frame at that instant and display the captured frame. Further the ability of the code to press the load button and reload the video frame should be maintained.

Presently I am using this code -

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import cv2
import ImageTk
from PIL import *
import Image
import Tkinter as tk

def image_capture(queue):
    vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        flag, frame=vidFile.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.cv.CV_BGR2RGB)
        queue.put(frame)
        cv2.waitKey(10)

def update_all(root, imagelabel, queue, process, var):
    if var.get()==True:
        global im
        im = queue.get()
        a = Image.fromarray(im)
        b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=a)
        imagelabel.configure(image=b)
        imagelabel._image_cache = b
        root.update()
        root.after(0, func=lambda: update_all(root, imagelabel, queue, process, var))
    else:
        print var.get()
        root.quit()

def playvideo(root, imagelabel, queue, var):

    global im
    p = Process(target=image_capture, args=(task,))
    p.start()
    update_all(root, imagelabel, queue, p, var)
    root.mainloop()
    p.terminate()
    if var.get()==False:
        try:
            cv2.imwrite("capturedFrame.jpg",im[:, :, ::-1])
            a = Image.fromarray(im)
            imagelabel.configure(image=a)
            imagelabel._image_cache = im
        except Exception,e:
            print e
    var.set(True)
    print 'finishing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        task = Queue()
        root = tk.Tk()
        image_label = tk.Label(master=root)
        image_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
        background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='img.jpg')
        image_label['image'] = background
        button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        button_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=1)

        load_button = tk.Button(master=button_frame, text='Load video',command=lambda: playvideo(root, image_label, task, switch))
        load_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')

        #Click button
        switch = tk.BooleanVar(master=root, value=True, name='switch')
        stop_button = tk.Button(master=button_frame, text='Click',command=lambda: switch.set(False))
        stop_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

        #quit button
        quit_button = tk.Button(master=button_frame, text='Quit',command=root.destroy)
        quit_button.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='ew')
        root.mainloop()

    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

This code clicks the image on click button, even saves the image, but throws an exception -

```
image "<Image.Image image mode=RGB size=640x480 at 0x5494FA8>" doesn't exist
```

Though the code works, but is there any better method to click from a webcam and save those clicked images. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the current frame from the camera and keep streaming the flux, you should associate your click button action with an independent function, let's call saveImage(queue) as follows:

```
def saveImage(queue):
    img = queue.get()
    cv2.imwrite("capturedFrame.jpg",img)
```

and the click button can be declare as follows:

```
click_button = tk.Button(master=button_frame, text='Click',command=lambda: saveImage(task))
```

where 'task' is the queue that you initiate in your main function.